# ms crm 2011 reload new window

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've copied a quote (with all quotedetails) and open it in an new window. Now I want to reload the new window to recalculate total amount of the new quote.

How can I reload the new window? 
If I put it in Onload of a window then I have an endless loop, because the window is reloading all the time.

Which is the best way to do this ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did my reply helped? If so, check it as an answer. If not, please explain what's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be reloading all the time. Not unless you call for it. Although, if you perform a save operation, a reload will be executed to refresh the frame. You're sparse with the details but I'm guessing that you want to recalculate the values on load but not store them.

In case you'd like to store the values directly after calculations have been performed (as opposed to letting the user click *save*), you can invoke `save()` method. And the right place to invoke calculations would in my view be in `onchange()` for the field(s) that you copy the values to.

Ultimately, there are two more approaches. The first is creating a plugin that will fire just before you retrieve an instance and populate the fields.

The other, and this is just a guess, would be adding a new button to the ribbon. We've done that a few months ago. In addition to *save&new* we also have now *save&copy*, which saves the current form to the database and opens a new one with pre-populated values from the newly closed one.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Is it possible to start the recalculation of the values on another way?

Comment: @Thomas The recalculations don't cause you the error. You saving them does. By your question I'm guessing that you wish to save the calculated values automatically just as they've been computed. See my addition to the answer.